# Dealing with different names for keys in terminal (e.g. RET vs <return>)

Tags: emacs

When Emacs runs under terminal, it sees different names for certain keys compared to when it's running as a GTK app (`RET` instead of `<return>`, `TAB` instead of `<tab>`, etc.)  For some custom keybindings that involve these keys, I have to define them twice, one for the "GTK" form of return or tab, once for the "terminal" form.  Also, org-mode appears to override the `<tab>` keybinding, but not the `TAB` binding, leading to inconsistent behavior.  Is there a way to translate the "terminal" keys to the "GTK" keys (for lack of better terminology) or somehow avoid this mess otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system in place for situations like this. Emacs defines two keymaps `key-translation-map` and `function-key-map` that are intended to translate keys from one form to another.

Comment: I'll tentatively accept the answer because it helps with the original question.  However, it turns out that the issue is more subtle.  For instance, under GTK, `<return>` is translated to `RET` in the minibuffer.  If I use something like `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "RET") (kbd "<return>"))`, `<return>` is now sent to the minibuffer and it breaks.